# how to type convert IDispatchEx to TAutoIntfObject in delphi

Tags: delphi

how to type convert IDispatchEx to TAutoIntfObject in delphi.

```
var
    ValueEx: IDispatchEx;
    MyPropertyValue: Variant;
    AutoObj: TAutoIntfObject; 
begin
    Supports( IDispatch(MyPropertyValue), IDispatchEx, ValueEx );
    AutoObj := ValueEx as TAutoIntfObject; ---> this line occured error
end;
```

Comment: Supports returns an interface, not a Delphi object.  Have you looked at e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502832/in-delphi-is-it-possible-to-bind-an-interface-to-an-object-that-doesnt-implemen

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using? Casting an interface to its implementing class type is natively supported in Delphi 2010 and later only. In earlier versions, you would have to obtain the object pointer through manual approaches, either through a custom interface that returns the `Self` pointer, or by digging through the interface's vtable directly